# Can't get the right alignment using Stack

Tags: flutter

I am trying to write rotated text on the right border of a `Container`. If the text is simply one letter I can get the right result:

[image]

However, if I make the text bigger the position will start shifting to the center:

[image]

Here's the code:

```dart
Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.yellow),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Transform.rotate(
            angle: pi / 2,
            child: Text('more char'),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
```

Comment: Try changing Align to Positioned.Fill() and wrap the widget inside Positioned with Center()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  Align(
    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
    child: RotatedBox(
      quarterTurns: 1,
      child: Text('more char'),
    ),
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.yellow),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: Transform.rotate(
        angle: pi / 2,
        child: Container(
          child: Text('More char'),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```

Comment: why bottom 10 and not bottom 15?

Comment: that's up to you, for reference I have added just 10.